# How to rewrite a URL with ID to short url with ID

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have some proplem with seo and need rewrite pages with id
from

```
example.com/media/player/related.php?mode=related&video_id=12345
```

to

```
example.com/video/12345
```

All id parameters have numerical values. `RewriteEngine On`

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to *redirect* from `/media/player/related.php?mode=related&video_id=12345` (containing a query string) to `/video/12345` then you could do something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mode=related&video_id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^media/player/related.php$ /video/%1 [R=302,L]
```

This matches the source URL as mentioned in the example, except the value of the `video_id` URL param is captured and assumed to be numeric only. This also just tests that the query string *starts with* the stated query string, so any additional URL params are ignored.

Change the `302` (temporary) status to `301` if this is intended to be a permanent redirect, but only after you have checked that it's working OK. (301s are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.)

Presumably, you have existing directives or some kind of *front controller* that already *rewrites* `/video/12345` back to the "real" URL? The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to prevent a redirect loop, assuming this is the case.